# Display content of file in zabbix

Tags: monitoring, zabbix, logfile

I have zabbix server to monitor linux server, I am trying to read daily backup file and display all contents of file on zabbix, how can I do that.

I tried to do the following:

first item

**TYPE: Zabbix_agent (Active)**
**log[/var/opt/backup,]**

second item

**TYPE: Zabbix_agent (Active)**
**vfs.file.contents[/var/opt/backup]**

but there is no data retrieved, and should I do anything in trigger...

Comment: Do you need to react to specific events (ie: "somestring" found on /var/log/yourlog) or you just want to centralize your logging?

Comment: Do you have any other active item working on that agent? Does zabbix user have access to that file? Does the `vfs.file.contents` item work as a passive item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure that the `EnableRemoteCommands` parameter is set to 1 and uncommented in the respective `zabbix_agentd.conf`. **Note**: Remote commands do not work with active Zabbix agents.
2. Create an item with that key: `system.run[cat /var/opt/backup]`. Don't forget to choose the appropriate "Type of information" when creating the item.